# Is it possible to show upload progress on a page after clicking submit on a non-ajax html form?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to show upload progress on a page after clicking submit on a non-ajax html form? Would Socket.io allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not if you're using a standard http form submission to upload the file. You will have to use some sort of flash or ajax upload script which doesn't require the current page on the browser to be submitted to do the upload.